# British English phrase "dot and carry one"

Tags: idioms, british-english

I've been re-reading 'Treasure Island' by Stevenson, and, at one point a character says, "... my pulse went dot and carry one" meaning, I think, that his pulse started racing.

Has anyone heard this idiom before? Can anyone tell me specifically to what it refers? The 'carry one' seems mathematical.

Comment: Is this what we call general reference? Googling easily brings up the answer. http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-dot1.htm

Comment: @bev, did you do any research before posting this question?

Comment: @simchona - posting the question here is my research.

Comment: @bev: EL&U shouldn't be the first place you go. The reason for downvotes is that a question "does not show any research effort": please Google before asking future questions.

Comment: @Jeremy - thx for the pointer. I just read your link and my feeling is quite the reverse of what the author says, "It’s easy to see how dot and carry one could have later taken on the idea of a hop and a skip or a missing beat." To me, after reading that explanation, I can't see why Stevenson uses that idiom in that context. Nothing on that page, in any way, makes sense of the idiom as Stevenson used it. I'll wait and see whether anyone here has any other suggestions.

Comment: @simchona - I'm sorry, truly, but I'll have to disregard your advice. This is a great place for doing research. I don't really care for upvotes or downvotes, since they have no meaning apart from providing a method for some people to show approval/disapproval, which I don't honestly care about. Any living and thinking human will receive approval and disapproval all the time for all sorts of things. Please rethink your attitude of frowning on people doing research here. This is precisely what stackexchange is for.

Comment: @bev: EL&U is not meant to be a complicated way of getting other people to google things for you. If you have googled or done other research, but have not found satisfactory results, please explain what you found and why it's unsatisfactory or else this question will be closed.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? This is a perfectly valid question, well-formatted, understandable, and answerable.

Comment: +1, interesting question. I'm a bit sorry this question hasn't received more answers, preferably complete. :/

Comment: +N for "posting the question here is my research." -- But seriously, ESL (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2) is the place, not ELU.

Comment: @Kris This is not about a standard English phrase and has nothing to do with ESL.  The only results you get googling this are discussing this one usage.

Comment: Folks, [Google is not general reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference). Really. I certainly don't know of a generally-available reference source specifically designed to answer this type of question - dictionaries don't generally include random phrases.

Comment: This question was initially closed (1 Oct 2011), then reopened (27 Oct 2011). In Nov 2012 there was an attempt to close it again, but the "Leave Open" votes prevailed. And now we have another attempt to close this question, but none of the 3 close-voters has bothered to explain their reasoning. **I think it's both interesting and useful, so I'm voting to Leave Open.**

Answer (score 7):

According to [worldwidewords.org](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-dot1.htm), "dot and carry one" (as used in the book) had implications that the heart skipped a beat. This would coincide with Barrie's answer about what the true meaning is. Referencing a Captain Francis Grose in his *Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue* from 1785, the site also offers an alternate explanation:

> (Grose also mentions hopping-Giles as another slang term of the time for a person with a limp [...])

The [notes provided](http://www.kellscraft.com/treasureislandnotes.html) at the end of an [online version](http://www.kellscraft.com/treasureislandcontent.html) of the book seems to have come to the same conclusion defining the meaning as,

> An irregular "thump, thump."

(An irregular pulse / heartbeat equates to a skipped beat. In other words, the character could have just said he/she felt [heart palpitations](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003081.htm).)

Answer (score 5):

Dot and carry one is a technique used when adding numbers in a ledger. In effect you place a dot in the first column and then add a unit to the next column (known as carrying one).
Historically book keepers or accountants using pens would have made a ".1" (dot dash) sound when they updated their accounts, this sounds like a person with a limp or old fashioned prosthetic walking.
The metaphors is therefore likens the sound of a person walking with a limp or prosthetic to the "dot dash" sound a pen makes when a bookmaker adds numbers in a ledger.

Answer (score 3):

I too had supposed it to be mathematical, but Brewer gives

> An infant just beginning to toddle; one who limps in walking; a person
>   who has one leg longer than the other.

Comment: While I'm sure OP is grateful for some kind of answer, I'm unsure how this "answer" answers OP's question. It doesn't explain what `dot and carry one` means in the context given. I find this answer to be incomplete and somewhat unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

"Dot and carry one" is found in the poem "Gunga Din" by Rudyard Kipling. Gunga Din is an Indian "Bisti", a servant who carried water for the troops, Kipling writes, referring to the Bisti carrying a water flask during a battle, "He would dot and carry one 'til the longest day was done, and he didn't seem to know the use of fear." I presume it meant that he scrambled to keep up with the troops.
Jackaline Winspear (in the novel "Birds of a Feather," uses the term to describe her assistant, whose leg had been seriously wounded in WW I, coming up a flight of stairs. This would seem to mean that his step was irregular because he had to favor his wounded leg.
Allen Peacock, April 8, 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago I learned this ditty in northern England:

> Dot and carry one Brown goes,
> Everybody in town knows
> To the Dog and Gun down goes he.
> With his gammy leg stuck straight out before him

---

Sorry, I cannot remember the rest, as I say it was probably 70 years ago, but that was a term we used for someone with a pronounced limp.  Maybe the dot was originally the mark or sound of a crutch or wooden leg,
and then the other good leg was carried forward.

Margaret (aged 90)  now in Powell River, B.C. Canada

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "dot-and-carry-one" is used by Mary Stewart in Chapter 6 of her novel [*The Gabriel Hounds*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tOE5AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&dq=%22Then+I+recklessly+dragged+the+bed+away+from+the+wall.+It+came+across+the+cracked+marble%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin5JGWz_ztAhVDGs0KHXObDu0Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Then%20I%20recklessly%20dragged%20the%20bed%20away%20from%20the%20wall.%20It%20came%20across%20the%20cracked%20marble%22&f=false), published in 1967.

She wrote,

> Then I recklessly dragged the bed away from the wall. It came across the cracked marble with a dot-and-carry-one screech of broken castors.

I take the "dot-and-carry-one" to mean that the bed moved in a series of bumps and shifts.

So I am thinking the pulse of the character in Treasure Island had become irregular - with longer than usual gaps between the beats, the "dot" being the beat and the "carry one" being the gap between beats.

Answer (score -1):

My mother always used the expression when referring to someone who was somewhat less than sane, i.e., slightly doolally.

Comment: Hello Brutus. Anecdotal material is not considered suitable for an 'answer' on ELU; this would make a good 'comment'. But, as all of us have found, you can't 'comment' until you've amassed a few points.

Answer (score -2):

I think "dot and carry one" is walking up stairs one step at a time. Stepping on the first step then bringing the other foot to join the first, then repeat all the way up.

Comment: It's certainly used in that context; I'm not sure it's the origin.